# Login and call an admin component function on Joomla

Tags: php, authentication, curl, joomla

I Need to call a function that is inside a joomla component, but to do this, I need to be logged in admin, I need to call this function inside a php script, that runs in the terminal.

What i have tried:

1. Use cURL to login and then call the function
2. Instantiate the component controller and call the function

Neither options works, on the first I cant figure out how to log in (I tried a script from other question not worked) and then use the 'session' to call the function.

On the second, i can instantiate a 'regular' component, but for a admin component i cant instatiate.

I tried to login using this question, and many similar others:
[Joomla 2.5 login with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766387/joomla-2-5-login-with-curl)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I Solved the problem with another strategy.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: So this page is doomed to be abandoned/unresolved then?  This is not good for reasearchers.  Ideally, I wish this page was migrated to JSE, then you posted an educational explanation of how you resolved your question.